# Azure API App (Preview) Provisioning Failed

Tags: azure-api-apps

When I attempt to make a new Azure API App through Visual Studio the provisioning fails with the following message.

```
Registering the Azure resource provider
Creating the Azure resource group alex.west-us.RG
Creating the API App alexprofessionaltest
Exception: Following errors occured during the deployment:
Error during deployment for resource 'alexprofessionaltest' in resource group 'alex.west-us.RG': BadRequest: .
Error during deployment for resource 'ApiApp_ac06b41fc7d941d4b410befbb5306f85' in resource group 'alex.west-us.RG': ResourceDeploymentFailure: The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'..
Azure API App provisioning failed
```

I'm using VS 14.0.25425.01 Update 3 and "Common Azure Tools 1.8"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was running an out of date SDK. Downloading the latest one [from here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/) got me all patched up and able to create API Apps again.